# Identity Framework Get Application User after login

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I use a custom class for automatic login the user with identity Framework then I use the ApplicationUser to get multiple information but now, ApplicationUser is null when login in is successfull, here's my code :

```
_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, pwd, RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
ApplicationUser = _userManager.GetUserAsync(_signInManager.Context.User).Result;
```

The code is not in a controller but in a custom class for login and user management, it work well yesterday but I cannot figure why it doesn't work now.

'_signInManager' and '_userManager' is created by dependency injection in the constructor.

**EDIT**
I've moved the code to a controller where I can access "User", the login is successfull but User.Identity.isAuthenticated is False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you execute `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` you need to have the cookie set on your request. This means you'll need to allow for a redirection to another page to happen before you can use `Context.User`.

If you need `ApplicationUser` just after the sign-in just use `_userManager.FindByNameAsync(username)`.